# Dask resolved to no files error when reading from Google Cloud with glob string

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-storage, dask

I've just updated Dask to 2.8.0, gcsfs 0.4.0. I didn't have this issue with dask 2.5

I'm trying to read a csv from google cloud storage using a glob string and I get the following error:

```
df = dd.read_csv('gcs://BQ-Extracts/result_20191118101535_*.csv'
                 ,  storage_options={'token': 'key.json'})


        OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-6ec3897e38c7> in <module>
      1 df = dd.read_csv('gcs://BQ-Extracts/result_20191118101535_*.csv'
----> 2                  ,  storage_options={'token': 'key.json'})

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\csv.py in read(urlpath, blocksize, collection, lineterminator, compression, sample, enforce, assume_missing, storage_options, include_path_column, **kwargs)
    576             storage_options=storage_options,
    577             include_path_column=include_path_column,
--> 578             **kwargs
    579         )
    580 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\csv.py in read_pandas(reader, urlpath, blocksize, collection, lineterminator, compression, sample, enforce, assume_missing, storage_options, include_path_column, **kwargs)
    403         compression=compression,
    404         include_path=include_path_column,
--> 405         **(storage_options or {})
    406     )
    407 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\bytes\core.py in read_bytes(urlpath, delimiter, not_zero, blocksize, sample, compression, include_path, **kwargs)
     94 
     95     if len(paths) == 0:
---> 96         raise IOError("%s resolved to no files" % urlpath)
     97 
     98     if blocksize is not None:

OSError: gcs://BQ-Extracts/result_20191118101535_*.csv resolved to no files
```

If I indicate a file path explicitly without '*' everything works perfect.

In this particular case I need to read one file from GCS so the path could be specified without a glob string. However, the abovementioned code is a part of function which extracts data from BigQuery to GCS and then reads to dask dataframe. So that's why glob string is always used

**UPD** Seems that latest version of gcsfs and fsspec cause the issue. Everything works fine with fsspec 0.5.2 and gcsfs 0.3.0.

Would appreciate if anyone helps to resolve the issue with gcsfs 0.4.0

Comment: Please do not duplicate your posts https://github.com/dask/gcsfs/issues/205

Comment: Please follow up the post on [github](https://github.com/dask/gcsfs/issues/205) for further discussion.